# Why isn't this MATLAB class holding on to its properties?

Tags: matlab, class, matlab-figure

There must be something very simple that I'm missing here. I have a MATLAB class which creates a figure containing two push-buttons, each button calls the same function, but the handles for those buttons aren't retained within that function, and I don't know why.

Here's the class, simplified...

```
classdef Test

    properties
        Figure
        ButtonA
        ButtonB
    end

    methods    
        function app = Test()       
            app.Figure = figure();

            app.ButtonA = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', ...
                'String', 'Button A', ...
                'Position', [10, 10, 100, 20], ...
                'Callback', @app.PressButton);
            app.ButtonB = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', ...
                'String', 'Button B', ...
                'Position', [10, 120, 100, 20], ...
                'Callback', @app.PressButton);
        end

        function PressButton(app, Button, ~)
            Button
            app.ButtonA
            app.ButtonB
        end
    end
end
```

If I call it it opens the figure, and displays the handle numbers for the buttons:

```
>> T = Test
T = 
  Test with properties:

     Figure: 8
    ButtonA: 745.000122070313
    ButtonB: 103.002319335938
>> T.ButtonA
ans = 745.000122070313
>> T.ButtonB
ans = 103.002319335938
```

If I press Button A, the function returns two empty values, as if the properties have not been set:

```
Button =
          745.000122070313
ans =
     []
ans =
     []
```

If I press Button B, the function does return the value for button A, but an empty value for button B:

```
Button =
          103.002319335938
ans =
          745.000122070313
ans =
     []
```

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should subclass your class from handle. 
Check the difference between matlab's `value`-class and `handle`-class [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html).

To do so, change the first line in your code:

```
 classdef Test < handle
```

Comment: Yup, that's fixed it. I'll have a read of that link to see what it means. Thanks.